# Can't get activejdbc working?

Tags: java, activejdbc

I have the following classes:

```
package models;

public class Test extends activejdbc.Model
{
}
```

: and :

```
import activejdbc.*;
import models.Test;

public class ActiveJdbc
{
    public static void main(String args [])  throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("starting...");
        test();
    }


    public static void test() throws Exception
    {
        activejdbc.Base.open("org.h2.Driver", "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test", "sa", "");

        models.Test t = models.Test.findFirst("id = ??",1);
        String s = t.get("name").toString();
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

: but when I run it with :

```
java -cp .;../lib/h2.jar;../lib/activejdbc.jar;../lib/slf4j-simple.jar;../lib/javalite.jar ActiveJdbc
```

: I get the error :

```
starting...
Exception in thread "main" activejdbc.DBException: failed to determine Model class name, are you sure models have been instrumented?
        at activejdbc.Model$ClassGetter.getClassName(Model.java:1577)
        at activejdbc.Model.getClassName(Model.java:1546)
        at activejdbc.Model.getDaClass(Model.java:1538)
        at activejdbc.Model.getTableName(Model.java:1550)
        at activejdbc.Model.getMetaModel(Model.java:58)
        at activejdbc.Model.findFirst(Model.java:1073)
        at ActiveJdbc.test(ActiveJdbc.java:17)
        at ActiveJdbc.main(ActiveJdbc.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to determine Model class name, are you sure models have been instrumented?
```

: Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have since figured this out. You need to first run:

java -DoutputDirectory=. -cp .;activejdbc-instrumentation.jar;javassist.jar;activejdbc.jar;activejdbc.instrumentation.Main

Comment: The answer was correct at the time. I answered 4 years ago so I will have to refresh myself before I answer you.