# ActiveJDBC - how to define models

Tags: java, orm, activejdbc

you are trying to work with models, but no models are found. Maybe you have no models in project, or you did not instrument the models. It is expected that you have a file activejdbc_models.properties on classpath

```
Caused by: activejdbc.InitException: you are trying to work with models, but no models are found. Maybe you have no models in project, or you did not instrument the models. It is expected that you have a file activejdbc_models.properties on classpath
at activejdbc.ModelFinder.findModels(ModelFinder.java:46)
at activejdbc.Registry.init(Registry.java:97)
at activejdbc.Model.<clinit>(Model.java:53)
... 2 more
```

thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this has already been answered:
[Can't get activejdbc working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780362/cant-get-activejdbc-working)

Basically, you are missing an instrumentation step after compilation. If you are using Maven see this simple example: https://github.com/javalite/simple-example

if you are using Ant, see this: https://github.com/javalite/ant-example
Refer:
     http://javalite.io/getting_started

thanks

Comment: and if I am using gradle :D

Comment: What if I am NOT missing instrumentation step, but it still can't find model?

Comment: @SuzanCioc, do you have a specific error or exception?